# Change log directory for default system log of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a installation of SQL Server express which I configured with an `.ini` file, now I have discovered that there are logfiles which are written into the folder

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
```

In my case this produces errors, it is required that nothing will be written into this folder. So my question is, how can I configure this in my `.ini` file?

[image]

Here is my ini file

```
    ;SQL Server 2017 Configuration File
    [OPTIONS]

    ; By specifying this parameter and accepting Microsoft R Open and Microsoft R Server terms, you acknowledge that you have read and understood the terms of use. 

    IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS="False"

    ; Specifies a Setup work flow, like INSTALL, UNINSTALL, or UPGRADE. This is a required parameter. 

    ACTION="Install"

    ; Detailed help for command line argument ROLE has not been defined yet. 

    ROLE="AllFeatures_WithDefaults"

    ; Specifies that SQL Server Setup should not display the privacy statement when ran from the command line. 

    SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE="False"

    ; By specifying this parameter and accepting Microsoft R Open and Microsoft R Server terms, you acknowledge that you have read and understood the terms of use. 

    IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS="False"

    ; Use the /ENU parameter to install the English version of SQL Server on your localized Windows operating system. 

    ENU="True"

    ; Setup will not display any user interface. 

    QUIET="true"

    ; Setup will display progress only, without any user interaction. 

    QUIETSIMPLE="false"

    ; Parameter that controls the user interface behavior. Valid values are Normal for the full UI,AutoAdvance for a simplied UI, and EnableUIOnServerCore for bypassing Server Core setup GUI block. 

    ;UIMODE="Normal"

    ; Specify whether SQL Server Setup should discover and include product updates. The valid values are True and False or 1 and 0. By default SQL Server Setup will include updates that are found. 

    UpdateEnabled="True"

    ; If this parameter is provided, then this computer will use Microsoft Update to check for updates. 

    USEMICROSOFTUPDATE="False"

    ; Specify the location where SQL Server Setup will obtain product updates. The valid values are "MU" to search Microsoft Update, a valid folder path, a relative path such as .\MyUpdates or a UNC share. By default SQL Server Setup will search Microsoft Update or a Windows Update service through the Window Server Update Services. 

    UpdateSource="MU"

    ; Specifies features to install, uninstall, or upgrade. The list of top-level features include SQL, AS, IS, MDS, and Tools. The SQL feature will install the Database Engine, Replication, Full-Text, and Data Quality Services (DQS) server. The Tools feature will install shared components. 

    FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,SNAC_SDK

    ; Displays the command line parameters usage 

    HELP="False"

    ; Specifies that the detailed Setup log should be piped to the console. 

    INDICATEPROGRESS="False"

    ; Specifies that Setup should install into WOW64. This command line argument is not supported on an IA64 or a 32-bit system. 

    X86="False"

    ; Specify a default or named instance. MSSQLSERVER is the default instance for non-Express editions and SQLExpress for Express editions. This parameter is required when installing the SQL Server Database Engine (SQL), or Analysis Services (AS). 

    INSTANCENAME="SQLEXPRESS"

    ; Specify the root installation directory for shared components.  This directory remains unchanged after shared components are already installed. 

    INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

    ; Specify the root installation directory for the WOW64 shared components.  This directory remains unchanged after WOW64 shared components are already installed. 

    INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"

    ; Specify the Instance ID for the SQL Server features you have specified. SQL Server directory structure, registry structure, and service names will incorporate the instance ID of the SQL Server instance. 

    INSTANCEID="SQLEXPRESS"

    ; TelemetryUserNameConfigDescription 

    SQLTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS"

    ; TelemetryStartupConfigDescription 

    SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

    ; Specify the installation directory. 

    INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

    ; Agent account name 

    AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT-AUTORITÄT\Netzwerkdienst"

    ; Auto-start service after installation.  

    AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"

    ; CM brick TCP communication port 

    COMMFABRICPORT="0"

    ; How matrix will use private networks 

    COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL="0"

    ; How inter brick communication will be protected 

    COMMFABRICENCRYPTION="0"

    ; TCP port used by the CM brick 

    MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT="0"

    ; Startup type for the SQL Server service. 

    SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

    ; Level to enable FILESTREAM feature at (0, 1, 2 or 3). 

    FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"

    ; Set to "1" to enable RANU for SQL Server Express. 

    ENABLERANU="True"

    ; Specifies a Windows collation or an SQL collation to use for the Database Engine. 

    SQLCOLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"

    ; Account for SQL Server service: Domain\User or system account. 

    SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"

    ; Set to "True" to enable instant file initialization for SQL Server service. If enabled, Setup will grant Perform Volume Maintenance Task privilege to the Database Engine Service SID. This may lead to information disclosure as it could allow deleted content to be accessed by an unauthorized principal. 

    SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="False"

    ; Windows account(s) to provision as SQL Server system administrators. 

    SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="#_COMPUTERNAME_#\Administrator"

    ; The default is Windows Authentication. Use "SQL" for Mixed Mode Authentication. 

    SECURITYMODE="SQL"

    ; The number of Database Engine TempDB files. 

    SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT="1"
    IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS=1
    IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms=1

    ; Specifies the initial size of a Database Engine TempDB data file in MB. 

    SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE="8"

    ; Specifies the automatic growth increment of each Database Engine TempDB data file in MB. 

    SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH="64"

    ; Specifies the initial size of the Database Engine TempDB log file in MB. 

    SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE="8"

    ; Specifies the automatic growth increment of the Database Engine TempDB log file in MB. 

    SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH="64"

    ; Provision current user as a Database Engine system administrator for %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Express. 

    ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True"

    ; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the TCP/IP protocol. 

    TCPENABLED="1"

    ; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the Named Pipes protocol. 

    NPENABLED="1"

    ; Startup type for Browser Service. 

    BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled"
    SAPWD="foobar"
```

Comment: *"it is required that nothing will be written into this folder"*, why, out of interest? Why if this a "requirement"?

Comment: Its a requirement of a customer, that nothing must be written into c:/program files folder ...

Comment: This is a prime XY problem example. You installed SQL Server there, so you have already failed them there. All the system databases will be there too. Have you moved those..? This is the customer (for lack of better words) making stupid depends due to lack of knowledge.

Comment: You are right, but as you know customer is king :-) . Actually I am trying to move these folders wth permissions and then create a link to the new destination in the installtion dir.

Comment: *"customer is king"* not when they make stupid decisions based on a lack of knowledge and ignorance. Then it's up to you to educate them. If we (developers) always did what the customer asked, we would be in a world of pain. Customers are (almost always) not technologically skilled, and don't know what they are really asking half the time. This is certainly one of those times; seeing as the requirement is that nothing can be put into `Program Files`; as that'll include SQL Server itself. If you *really* need to do that, you need to uninstall the instance, and reinstall it to another directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *do* need to change the location of log files, you need to use [Startup Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-service-startup-options?view=sql-server-ver15). In this case you need the parameters `-e`.

Open the SQL Server Configuration manager and find your instance. Right Click and open its properties and go to the Startup Parameters Pane. Then add the relevant new Startup Parameter, for example: `-e C:\SQLErrorLogs\LOG\ERRORLOG`. You will need to ensure the service account has access to the new path, and then restart your instance.

Of course, like I said in the comments, it seems odd that that it is a "requirement" that nothing is written to the `ERRORLOG` folder, and I suspect this is an XY Problem.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to set that programatically for example via registry?

Comment: [Change SQL Startup Parameters with PowerShell](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/change-sql-startup-parameters-with-powershell) @AlPhaba